# C# and Ajax filtering (4 filters, multiple options in each)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, filter

To explain that better I have 4 types of filters: Location, Type, Grade, Facilities.

I currently have it all working but every filter works as an OR so that it just adds on the results. I am wanting it to be an AND (&&) between the filter types and each type of the same filter becomes OR. So an example would be "Scotland || England && Hotels && 4 Star || 5 Star && Children's Play Area || Pool.

I tried creating a list that removed additions that were not equal to the results but it would fail if you didn't start with location.

Here is my current code that works as just all OR filters.

```
// Get by Filters //
    public String GetAccomFilterPages(Int32 ModelID, Int32 page, String location, String type, String grade, String facility)
    {
        // Builder Start //
        AccommodationList Model = Umbraco.TypedContent(ModelID) as AccommodationList;
        StringBuilder HTMLAccom = new StringBuilder();

        //Build list and use | to split //
        List<Accommodation> Results = new List<Accommodation>();
        Boolean noFilter = true;

        // Location
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
        {
            String[] Locations = location.Split('|');
            foreach (String locSearch in Locations)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(locSearch))
                {
                    foreach (var locItem in Model.Descendants<Accommodation>().Where(x => x.Location.Where(xx => xx.Name.Replace("&", "and") == locSearch.Replace("&", "and")).Count() > 0))
                    {
                        if (!Results.Contains(locItem))
                        {
                            Results.Add(locItem);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            noFilter = false;
        }

        // Accom Types
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
        {
            String[] Types = type.Split('|');
            foreach (String typSearch in Types)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(typSearch))
                {
                    foreach (var typItem in Model.Descendants<Accommodation>().Where(x => x.AccommodationType.Where(xx => xx.Name.Replace("&", "and") == typSearch.Replace("&", "and")).Count() > 0))
                    {
                        if (!Results.Contains(typItem))
                        {
                           Results.Add(typItem);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            noFilter = false;
        }

        // Grades
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(grade))
        {
            String[] Grades = grade.Split('|');
            foreach (String gradeSearch in Grades)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(gradeSearch))
                {
                    foreach (var gradeItem in Model.Descendants<Accommodation>().Where(x => x.GradeRating.Where(xx => xx.Name.Replace("&", "and") == gradeSearch.Replace("&", "and")).Count() > 0))
                    {
                        if (!Results.Contains(gradeItem))
                        {
                            Results.Add(gradeItem);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            noFilter = false;
        }

        // Facilities
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(facility))
        {
            String[] Facilities = facility.Split('|');
            foreach (String facSearch in Facilities)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(facSearch))
                {
                    foreach (var facItem in Model.Descendants<Accommodation>().Where(x => x.FacilitiesAvaliable.Where(xx => xx.Name.Replace("&", "and") == facSearch.Replace("&", "and")).Count() > 0))
                    {
                        if (!Results.Contains(facItem))
                        {
                            Results.Add(facItem);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            noFilter = false;
        }

        if (noFilter == true)
        {
            Results.AddRange(Model.Descendants<Accommodation>());
        }

        // End Filtering //
        int skip = 0;
        int take = 5;
        int totalNodes = Results.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalNodes / take);

        // Results Count //
        int lastIdOnPage = take;

        if (page != 1)
        {
            skip = take * (page - 1);
            lastIdOnPage = (totalNodes - skip);
            if (lastIdOnPage > take)
            {
                lastIdOnPage = skip + take;
            }
            else
            {
                lastIdOnPage = skip + lastIdOnPage;
            }

        }
        else if (take > totalNodes)
        {
            lastIdOnPage = totalNodes;
        }
        int firstIdOnPage = skip + 1;

        // Start Print of Page //
        // Loop through Accoms //

        foreach (Accommodation ACC in Results.Skip(skip).Take(take))
        {
            ....
    }

        // Filter Reset //
        if (noFilter == false)
        {
            HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<li><a onclick=\"GetAccomPages(1, false)\">Remove Filters</a></li>");
        }

        // Pagination Results //
        if (firstIdOnPage == lastIdOnPage)
        {
            HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<p>" + firstIdOnPage + " of " + totalNodes + " results</p>");
        }
        else if (lastIdOnPage == 0)
        {
            HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<p> No results</p>");
        }
        else
        {
            HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<p>" + firstIdOnPage + " - " + lastIdOnPage + " of " + totalNodes + " results</p>");
        }

        // Page Links //
        if (totalPages > 1)
        {
            int countPages = 0;
            HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<ul class=\"pagination\">");
            while (totalPages > countPages)
            {
                countPages++;
                HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<li " + (countPages == page ? "class=\"active\">" : "") + "<a onclick=\"GetAccomFilterPages(" + (countPages) + ")\">" + countPages + "</a></li>");
            }
            HTMLAccom.AppendLine("</ul>");
        }

        return HTMLAccom.ToString();
    }
```

Frontend JS/AJAX (without URL amending:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var page = @page + "";
    var ShowAll = @ShowAll + "";

    if (page != "")
        GetAccomPages(page, false)
    else
        GetAccomPages(1, false);
});

function GetAccomPages(page, ShowAll) {
...
}

function GetAccomFilterPages(page, location, type, grade, facility) {

    var filterName = [locFilterName, typeFilterName, gradeFilterName, facFilterName];
    for (name in filterName){
        if ($("#ft" + name).prop('checked')) {
            $("#ft" + name).prop('checked', false)
        } else {
            $("#ft" + name).prop('checked', true)
        }
    }

    var locFilterName = "";
    var typeFilterName = "";
    var gradeFilterName = "";
    var facFilterName = "";

    var rows = $('.chkLoc');
    $.each(rows, function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            locFilterName += $(this).val() + "|";
        }
    });

    var rows = $('.chkType');
    $.each(rows, function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            typeFilterName += $(this).val() + "|";
        }
    });

    var rows = $('.chkGrade');
    $.each(rows, function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            gradeFilterName += $(this).val() + "|";
        }
    });

    var rows = $('.chkFac');
    $.each(rows, function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            facFilterName += $(this).val() + "|";
        }
    });

    //alert(locFilterName + typeFilterName + gradeFilterName + facFilterName);

    var AC = "ModelID=" + @Model.Content.Id + "&page=" + page + "&location=" + locFilterName + "&type=" + typeFilterName + "&grade=" + gradeFilterName + "&facility=" + facFilterName;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Umbraco/Api/AccomAjax/GetAccomFilterPages",
            data: AC,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#GetAccom").html(data);
            }
        });

    }
```

This is a fully working OR filter That updates as you tick each check box so feel free to take some ideas from it if you wish (if you came across this looking for how to make one) but I need it to AND between each of the filters and I'm stuck in the mire as they would say. I'm also a PHP developer so if I have done anything redundant please do give some CC.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You would benefit form posting the code for the class Accommodation, as it would be easier to answer your question. Basically, what you should do is not to filter the result in stages, just save the different filter options and then do a linq-query with all the filter data, using or and and appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of a coworker (.Net Developer) we managed to get it. Any Constructive criticism is welcome but this is how ours works. The one difference in function that has changed from my intial question is that the last filter for Facilities, all facilities will be ANDs: example - Scotland || Ireland && Hotels && 4 Star || 2 Star && Pool && Gym && Bar. So for Facilities look closely as I switch what it is doing compared to the first 3.

Anyone looking at this for guidance, only my backend changed no front end changes. There is also a few extra things on the front end you will need, such as url filter and declaring a few empty variables such as page, showAll and such. and build your input checkboxs with relevant value and id names to match with your JS.

```
// Get by Filters //
        public String GetAccomFilterPages(Int32 ModelID, Int32 page, String location, String type, String grade, String facility)
        {
            // Builder Start //
            AccommodationList Model = Umbraco.TypedContent(ModelID) as AccommodationList;
            StringBuilder HTMLAccom = new StringBuilder();

            //Build list and use | to split //

            List<Accommodation> LocationResults = new List<Accommodation>();
            List<Accommodation> TypeResults = new List<Accommodation>();
            List<Accommodation> GradeResults = new List<Accommodation>();
            List<Accommodation> FacResults = new List<Accommodation>();
            List<Accommodation> Results = new List<Accommodation>();
            Boolean noFilter = true;

            // Location
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
            {
                String[] Locations = location.Split('|');
                foreach (String locSearch in Locations)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(locSearch))
                    {
                        foreach (var locItem in Model.Descendants<Accommodation>().Where(x => x.Location.Where(xx => xx.Name.Replace("&", "and") == locSearch.Replace("&", "and")).Count() > 0))
                        {
                            if (!LocationResults.Contains(locItem))
                            {
                                LocationResults.Add(locItem);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                noFilter = false;
            }
                // If no filters set to all descendants. Similar Else's work to make sure if a filter isn't used the filtering still works by defaulting to check through all descendants. 
            else
            {
                LocationResults.AddRange(Model.Descendants<Accommodation>());
            }

            // Accom Types
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
            {
                String[] Types = type.Split('|');
                foreach (String typSearch in Types)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(typSearch))
                    {
                        foreach (var typItem in LocationResults.Where(x => x.AccommodationType.Where(xx => xx.Name.Replace("&", "and") == typSearch.Replace("&", "and")).Count() > 0))
                        {
                            if (!TypeResults.Contains(typItem))
                            {
                                TypeResults.Add(typItem);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                noFilter = false;
            }
            else
            {
                TypeResults.AddRange(LocationResults);
            }


            // Grades
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(grade))
            {
                String[] Grades = grade.Split('|');
                foreach (String gradeSearch in Grades)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gradeSearch))
                    {
                        foreach (var gradeItem in TypeResults.Where(x => x.GradeRating.Where(xx => xx.Name.Replace("&", "and") == gradeSearch.Replace("&", "and")).Count() > 0))
                        {
                            if (!GradeResults.Contains(gradeItem))
                            {
                                GradeResults.Add(gradeItem);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                noFilter = false;
            }
            else
            {
                GradeResults.AddRange(TypeResults);
            }



            // Facilities
            //For this section we are using a 'for' since we are wanting to remove non-matching results

            FacResults.AddRange(GradeResults);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(facility))
            {
                String[] Facilities = facility.Split('|');
                foreach (String facSearch in Facilities)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(facSearch))
                    {
                        for (int i = FacResults.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            Accommodation currentAccom = FacResults[i];
                            if (currentAccom.FacilitiesAvaliable.Where(x => x.Name.Replace("&", "and") == facSearch.Replace("&", "and")).Count() == 0)
                            {
                                FacResults.Remove(currentAccom);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                noFilter = false;
            }

            if (noFilter == true)
            {
                Results.AddRange(Model.Descendants<Accommodation>());
            }
            else
            {
                Results.AddRange(FacResults);            
            }

            // End Filtering //
            int skip = 0;
            int take = 5;
            int totalNodes = Results.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalNodes / take);

            // Results Count //
            int lastIdOnPage = take;

            if (page != 1)
            {
                skip = take * (page - 1);
                lastIdOnPage = (totalNodes - skip);
                if (lastIdOnPage > take)
                {
                    lastIdOnPage = skip + take;
                }
                else
                {
                    lastIdOnPage = skip + lastIdOnPage;
                }

            }
            else if (take > totalNodes)
            {
                lastIdOnPage = totalNodes;
            }
            int firstIdOnPage = skip + 1;

            // Start Print of Page //
            // Loop through Accoms //

            foreach (Accommodation ACC in Results.Skip(skip).Take(take))
            {
                ...
            }

            // Filter Reset //
            if (noFilter == false)
            {
                HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<li><a onclick=\"GetAccomPages(1, false)\">Remove Filters</a></li>");
            }

            // Pagination Results //
            if (firstIdOnPage == lastIdOnPage)
            {
                HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<p>" + firstIdOnPage + " of " + totalNodes + " results</p>");
            }
            else if (lastIdOnPage == 0)
            {
                HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<p> No results</p>");
            }
            else
            {
                HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<p>" + firstIdOnPage + " - " + lastIdOnPage + " of " + totalNodes + " results</p>");
            }

            // Page Links //
            if (totalPages > 1)
            {
                int countPages = 0;
                HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<ul class=\"pagination\">");
                while (totalPages > countPages)
                {
                    countPages++;
                    HTMLAccom.AppendLine("<li " + (countPages == page ? "class=\"active\">" : "") + "<a onclick=\"GetAccomFilterPages(" + (countPages) + ")\">" + countPages + "</a></li>");
                }
                HTMLAccom.AppendLine("</ul>");
            }

            return HTMLAccom.ToString();
        }
```